# Creating equally spaced columns in right and left aligned columns in a Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have table with left and right aligned columns, I need to make equal spacing within columns.

[image: Image with not equaled spacing]

Something like

```
justify-content: space-between
```

But preferably without flexbox and grids, only via html tables.

```css
.mtable {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  table-layout: fixed;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.mtable th {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.mtable td {
  border-top: solid 1px #DADEE6;
  padding: 10px;
}

td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(n+3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="mtable">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Plaftorm</td>
    <td>Views</td>
    <td>Shows</td>
    <td>Fillrate</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telegram</td>
    <td>Android</td>
    <td>60 011"</td>
    <td>40 631</td>
    <td>70 %</td>
    <td>On moderation</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>WhatsApp</td>
    <td>iOS</td>
    <td>124 289"</td>
    <td>93 431</td>
    <td>43 %</td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it is clearly visible on 1200px+

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many columns you have you can do the following:

```
.mtable td {
  width: 10%
}
```

Depending on how many columns you have, would depend on the % value.

So for a 6 columns table it would be:

```
.mtable td {
 width: 16.6666666667%;
}
```

Comment: He wants the space between the columns to have the same width, not the columns themself

Answer (score 0):

Your columns already have equal sizes and equal spacing between them, it just isn't that obvious as the text doesn't run to the edge of the column. Adding a border around each cell will demonstrate that they're all exactly the same;

You don't need to do anything to ensure that the gap is the same between them -- it already is.

```css
.mtable {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  table-layout: fixed;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.mtable th {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.mtable td {
  border-top: solid 1px #DADEE6;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black; /* Added */
}

td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(n+3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="mtable">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Plaftorm</td>
    <td>Views</td>
    <td>Shows</td>
    <td>Fillrate</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telegram</td>
    <td>Android</td>
    <td>60 011"</td>
    <td>40 631</td>
    <td>70 %</td>
    <td>On moderation</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>WhatsApp</td>
    <td>iOS</td>
    <td>124 289"</td>
    <td>93 431</td>
    <td>43 %</td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Spacing not equal :(